# Bind public string property to TextBox text via content presenter in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a custom wpf control that I created in hopes of reusing it over and over to reduce time spent writing, or copying and pasting, a bunch of xaml code. It, seems, pretty simple. It's to be used for a Label and TextBox pair so:

```
Label here
[  this is the text box (or other control) ]
```

It's called like so:

```
<controls:LabeledContentControl Margin="5"
                            MaxHeight="25"
                            LabelText="{Binding LabelString}" 
                            Content="{Binding LabelTextBoxTestString, ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

or

```
<controls:LabeledContentControl Margin="5"
                            LabelText="{Binding LabelString}">
<TextBox Text="{Binding LabelTextBoxTestString, 
                        ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=True, 
                        UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, 
                        Delay=100}" />
</controls:LabeledContentControl>
```

The `LabeledContentControl` extends `ContentControl`, the c# code doesn't seem relevant as it's dependency properties and their setters. Along with the two constructors similar the ones implemented in the Microsoft reference documents for other controls that extend `ContentControl`

https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/HeaderedContentControl.cs

I'm having issues with binding the backing view model property/field set when using the first approach for the labeled content control.

The XAML code for the control is like such:

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type controls:LabeledContentControl}" TargetType="{x:Type controls:LabeledContentControl}">
<!-- other setters.... -->
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type controls:LabeledContentControl}">
            <Border Name="OuterBd" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" >
                <Border Name="InnerBd" Background="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="0">
                    <Border Name="Bd" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness="0">
                        <DockPanel>
                            <DockPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top" IsHitTestVisible="False">
                                <TextBlock x:Name="FieldRequiredInd" 
                                           Text="* " 
                                           Foreground="Red" 
                                           Visibility="Collapsed"
                                           DockPanel.Dock="Left"/>
                                <TextBlock x:Name="LabelTextBlock"
                                           DockPanel.Dock="Left"
                                           Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=LabelText, Mode=OneWay}" />
                            </DockPanel>

                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="CustomContent" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" 
                                              Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                              ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource LabeledContentControlDataTemplateSelector}"
                                              MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxHeight}"/>
                        </DockPanel>
                    </Border>
                </Border>
            </Border>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                ...
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

The template selector, again super basic, if the content is of type `string` using `GetType` a custom datatemplate for strings is used so that they'll be in a text box and editable.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="StringDataTemplate" DataType="{x:Type system:String}">
    <TextBox>
        <TextBox.Text>
            <Binding Path="." />
        </TextBox.Text>
    </TextBox>
</DataTemplate>

<local:LabeledContentControlDataTemplateSelector x:Key="LabeledContentControlDataTemplateSelector"
                                                 StringDataTemplate="{StaticResource StringDataTemplate}"/>
```

How do/can I bind `LabelTextBoxTestString` **correctly** so that when I update/type something in the text box generated by the `StringDataTemplate` that it will update the bound property in the ViewModel? Currently, when I use the first approach, when I type in the text box created by the `StringDataTemplate` the backing field isn't updated with the new content, but when using the second approach the backing field is updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need some modifications:

first is the correct `Binding` in your `TextBox.Text` to:

```
<TextBox.Text>
    <Binding Path="Content" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" />
</TextBox.Text>
```

then change the Binding of `ContentPresenter` to:

```
<ContentPresenter x:Name="CustomContent"
                  MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxHeight}"
                  Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=local:LabeledContentControl}, Path=Content, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                  ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource LabeledContentControlDataTemplateSelector}"
                  DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" />
```

now you can bind your control. And take care, that `Mode` is set to `TwoWay` for `Content` property (default is `OneWay`), thats why you didn't got a feedback:

```
<controls:LabeledContentControl Margin="5"
                        MaxHeight="25"
                        LabelText="{Binding LabelString}" 
                        Content="{Binding LabelTextBoxTestString, ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=True, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

Comment: saving grace sir/madam. Thanks for the help.